# Linear Gradient within Image tintColor React-Native

Tags: image, react-native, frontend, linear-gradients

I am trying to apply a gradient color to the concerned Image but it doesn't take effect. I tried integrating it while `tintColor` was within styles and when a prop. Can anyone please help if there are any other way to make it work, thanks.

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'

const grad = <LinearGradient colors={['#FFFF', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} 
style={{position:'absolute'}}></LinearGradient>


class DocSelection extends React.Component{

    render(){

        return(
<View style={styles.container}>
<TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Account")
            }}
            style={ {position: 'absolute',
            width:  45,
            height: 45,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            left: wp('5%'),
            top: hp('43%'),
            backgroundColor:'white',
            borderRadius: 45/2}}>
            <Image

              source={require("../Icons/account.png")}

              style={{ resizeMode: 'contain',
              width: 27.5,
              height: 27.5,


              }}
              tintColor= {grad}
            />

 </TouchableOpacity>

</View>

)}
```